# Como adicionar o sql server integration server em um projeto já existente?

Tags: ssis

Eu estou precisando integrar o ssis a um projeto que já foi começado, para importação de planilhas de excel e coisas do tipo.

Todos os tutorias que vejo mostra criando um ssis como se fosse um projeto novo, o que não é meu caso.

Como aplicar o SSIS em um projeto já existente?

Comment: Tente explicar melhor a pergunta. Pelo que percebi já existe um projeto que tem a importação de vários ficheiros, e o objetivo é adicionar um novo pacote de SSIS a essa solução/projeto. Já tentou adicionar um item existente, ou no servidor fazer o import do novo?

Comment: Não sei se ficou muito claro mas a duvida é bem essa mesmo, tenho algumas planilhas que são importadas em c# puro, e isso faz com que planilhas gigantescas fiquem extremamente lentas, com isso, decidiram mudar para esse ssis por ser mais robusto para esse tipo de situação, com isso, já tem boa parte do projeto que está pronto, e teria que mudar algumas partes do código para ao invés de ter essa importação, importar usando o SSIS, porém estou tendo dificuldades em como intregra-los

Comment: Então a melhor solução e ver tutoriais e colocar a mão na massa ;) link: https://www.sqlshack.com/using-ssis-packages-import-ms-excel-data-database/